# error ggplot al graficar un dataset

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hola: al ejecutar estas líneas de código en r, me sale este mensaje de error.

```
library(tidyverse)
ggplot(data = mpg)+
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = displ, y = hwy))
```

Mensaje de error:

> ggplot(data = mpg)+geom_point(mapping = aes(x = displ, y = hwy))
>   Error in vectbl_restore(xo, x) : objeto 'tibble_restore_impl' no encontrado

Comment: Bienvenido Alexander a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: No he podido reproducir tu error. Prueba iniciar un nueva sesión de R o eventualmente reinstala ggplot. Saludos

Comment: Gracias, desinstalé el nucleo de r y el paquete, posteriormente instale versiones más recientes y me funcionó. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba la siguiente corrección. Para mayor referencia consulta la siguiente [cheatsheet](https://github.com/rstudio/cheatsheets/raw/master/data-visualization-2.1.pdf).

```
library(tidyverse)
ggplot(data = mpg, aes(x = displ, y = hwy))+
  geom_point()
```